# how to make the bxslider goToSlide function not animate - just jump/appear on slide?

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am using the bxslider which in my option is a pretty awesome jquery slider plugin as far as sliders go.

http://bxslider.com/

I using the `goToSlide();` function.

```
bxslider.goToSlide(slide);
```

I am trying to get `goToSlide` to jump to the slide - instead of animating.

Can someone help? I made a fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/dHxAJ/1/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dunno if it has the option or not but if you edit the plugin any animate you see change duration to 0 and it will do what u want.

Comment: I know it doesn't have the option, but basically I'm using a URL parameter to fire this function when document loads. The parameter is the slide number. So I only need this not animate some when the page loads you dont see the slider move. But the slider needs to animate at all other times. Not sure if i'm up for editing the plugin anyway :/ Thanks

Comment: how about hiding it untill it completes it? ugly workaround but will work, if it has an event of `onFinish` or something then bind to it, if not you can create a queue.

Comment: Hmmm not a bad idea actually, thanks @eric.itzhak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just override css transitions to resolve this

full answer here
[How to move to the next slide without animation for BxSlider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179654/how-to-move-to-the-next-slide-without-animation-for-bxslider/20428940#20428940)

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way to jump to a slide without animating:

```
$('.slidejump-2').on('click', function(e) {
  slider.reloadSlider({
    startSlide:1,
  });
});
```

Or for your example:

```
JumpToSlide = function (slideNumber) {

        var slide = slideNumber - 1;

        bxslider.reloadSlider({
          startSlide:slide,
          pager: false,
            auto: false
        });


    };
```

This reloads the slider and sets the start frame to whatever you choose. 
Forked fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/richbruce/2audvybc/1/)