# How to move to the next slide without animation for BxSlider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, bxslider

I am using a jQuery plugin [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/options).

There are two custom buttons, `prev` and `next` to toggle the sliding.
However, there is a specific situation where I need to move to a slide without animation, I want it to be instant.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [available options](http://bxslider.com/options),

Set the option `speed` to `0`, you will not get any animation.

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  speed: 0,
  captions: true
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eyajuc/1/edit)

Comment: This works, but is there a way to change the speed back to what it was?

Comment: Nvm, I ended up adding an extra function to the plugin to change the speed.

Comment: Settings this to 0 breaks my pager. Setting the speed to 1 does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery:

```
$('#slider').bxSlider({...});

$('.pager-item').on('click', function(){
  // bx-slider instant slide hack

  $('#slider').addClass('instant-slide');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#slider').removeClass('instant-slide');
  }, 100);

});
```

SCSS:

```
#slider {
 &.instant-slide {
   -webkit-transition: 0.001s ease !important;
   transition: 0.001s ease !important;
 }
}
```

this works for me, can be adapted to use with goToSlide()

```
{ useCSS: true }
```

required.